# Administration of WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, esb

I have many WCF sites, but i need to administrate this sites, 
to specify your actions, to have an inventory, like the metada of every one
i read something about ESB in Biztalk, but my problem is the cost.
Exist some alternative to manage this situation?

Any help or sugestion, please
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should extend your question because Biztalk's ESB has nothing in common with administrating services. So what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) can help to a certain degree, or you might want to look at other tools out there like [SO-Aware](http://tellagostudios.com/products/so-aware%E2%84%A2)